# Rails Test on Rails Tutorial, ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently learning Ruby on Rails on Rails Tutorial. When I did rails test, I encountered this error.

## log

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
    app/models/user.rb:35:in `authenticated?'
    app/controllers/account_activations_controller.rb:4:in `edit'
    test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:35:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
```

## app/models/user.rb

```
def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(self.remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
end
```

## app/controllers/account_activations_controller.rb

```
def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.update_attribute(:activated,    true)
      user.update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
```

## test/integration/users_signup_test.rb

```
test "valid signup information with account activation" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "Example User",
                                         email: "user@example.com",
                                         password:              "password",
                                         password_confirmation: "password" } }
    end

    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    user = assigns(:user)
    assert_not user.activated?
    log_in_as(user)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    get edit_account_activation_path("invalid token", email: user.email)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: 'wrong')
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: user.email)
    assert user.reload.activated?
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert is_logged_in?
  end
end
```

Could you give me advice to solve this?

Comment: You're now at place where it shouldn't work. "The above code uses the authenticated? method to test if the account activation digest matches the given token, but at present this won’t work because that method is specialized to the remember token". Go further through the tutorial, and you'll fix the code and see "red-green-refactoring" cycle

Comment: I am at chapter 11. Is my code missing something related to remember token?

Comment: Are you at the end of the chapter? If yes, reread it from start and change you code corresponding to changes in tutorial. The changes are in 11.3.1, so if you're somewhere before it - just forgot about broken tests and move further, it will be all right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have given additional parameter to `authenticated?` method in `app/controllers/account_activations_controller.rb#edit` second line.

Remove it and this should work.

Comment: I changed `user.update_attribute(:activated,    true)
      user.update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)` to `user.activate`, but still same error appeared.

Comment: @五十嵐伸雄 Since you have created a method `authenticated?` in user model with one parameter and you are sending two parameter, that is what causing error. when I said remove it, I meant, this change
`user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])` => `user.authenticated?(:activation)`